# Using GPU for processing Inverse Distance Weighted within Project Modeler

Tags: qgis, performance, qgis-modeler, gpu

We are currently doing IDW interpolation within QGIS’s Project Modeler only it is taking over 24 hours to do one run.  And we have over 30 to do.

Is there any way we can get it to process the data using the computer’s GPU’s rather than the CPU in order to (significantly) increase the processing time?

I have heard about using Python’s "Multi Processing" however do not know how this could be integrated into the Project Modeler.

Comment: What parameters are you using for the IDW? Is IDW the best tool for this task? Could you share some data?

Comment: We are satisfied that IDW is the right tool to use.  And we have stretched out the area to 20m rather than 5m.  We can’t go any wider.  A 5m we were looking at over a week’s runtime which is why we settled on 20m.  We have two flood extents Raster files over a 10km x 10km area with ground level LIDAR data.  They are very large files.  Does that help?

Comment: Basically we are trying to replicate the interpolation shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6w-txc5k6w at the 9:42 mark.  Only with a much larger data set.

Comment: Is your data water levels in a river? what is the distance between the points? Have you tried the "Grid (Inverse Distance To a Power)" tool or the "IDW Interpolation" tool? Would running multiple instances of QGIS with smaller datasets be another option?

Comment: They are actually flood water surfaces.  So they extend out well beyond the river extent.  And no, I haven’t tried the Grid Inverse Distance tool.  What’s is that and how is it different to IDW/. And we are using the IDW Interpolations tool already.  What we are now trying is a different machine with greater RAM and better / faster CPU and that is speeding things up.  And the 10km x 10km I mentioned is already a (much) smaller subset of what we want to use.